# Payments pro not working in magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal

I have integrated Payments pro payment method in my magento2.1.7 site.

Refer screenshot.

[image]

I have referred this link for integrating Payments pro https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payments-pro.html

With Debit or Credit it is working and I can see the transaction amount in the merchant acount.

But when I click Paypal it is redirecting to checkout cart page. Please help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error showing up on cart page?

Comment: No it is not showing any errors.